# Switchable AMD Vega RX unclaimed

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I got myself one of these laptops with switchable graphics between Intel integrated and AMD Vega RX. I tried installing the amdgpu-pro drivers, which I managed to sign and `lsmod` shows that `amdgpu` has been loaded (I forced it by appending it to `/etc/modules`).

Running `lshw -c video` shows an unclaimed device: (incoming french)

```
  *-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ     
   description: Display controller
   produit: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   fabriquant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: c0
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   ressources: mémoireE/S:2f0-2ef mémoireE/S:2f0-2ef mémoire:2fe0000000-2fefffffff mémoire:2ff0000000-2ff01fffff portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:de400000-de43ffff mémoire:de440000-de45ffff

  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   produit: Intel Corporation
   fabriquant: Intel Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 2
   information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   ressources: mémoireE/S:2f0-2ef mémoireE/S:2f0-2ef irq:126 mémoire:2ffe000000-2ffeffffff mémoire:2f80000000-2f8fffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

When hitting `lspci`, only a single VGA device shows (`lspci -nnk | grep VGA`):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:83bb]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

How do I fix this unclaimed device?
My goal is to be able to use the switchable graphics on Ubuntu. I'm guessing the first step is fixing this and then figure out how to perform the switch. From the kernel documentation I should find the switcheroo in `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo`, but there's nothing there at the moment.